# Obrigar o Usuário a digitar um numero minimo de caracteres

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho no meu formulário o campo data que obriga o usuário a apenas números e caso outras opções não sejam selecionadas ele retornar um alert. Mas minha duvida é referente ao campo data já citado.
Como obrigo o usuário a digitar os 8 números da data, e caso não digite, ao dar submit, ele retornará algum erro como um alert?

Segue o que tenho pronto até agr:

```js
function formatar(mascara, documento){
  var i = documento.value.length;
  var saida = mascara.substring(0,1);
  var texto = mascara.substring(i);
  if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
    event.returnValue = false;
  }
  
  if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
            documento.value += texto.substring(0,1);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form class="got" method="GET" action="Dia_rtd.php" name="troca" onsubmit="return verifica()">

                <input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Data" name="Data_dd" OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" style="width:70px;"/> 
 <button class="css_btn_class" type="submit">Atualizar</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou postar uma resposta apenas com CSS as vezes pode te ajudar.

Primeiro, se vc puder mude o tipo do `input` de `text` para `date` use os atributos `min="2017-01-01"` ou `max="2200-12-31"` para delimitar até onde sua data pode ir.

Caso o usuário não preencha os requisitos do campo o CSS `input:invalid` vai colocar um borda vermelha no `input`, **veja no exemplo abaixo** *(essa validação é só no lado do cliente, não sei se atende no seu caso)*

```css
input:invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form class="got" method="GET" action="Dia_rtd.php" name="troca" onsubmit="return verifica()">
    <input type="date" min="2017-01-01" max="2200-12-31" placeholder="Data" name="Data_dd" OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" style="width:170px;"/>  
    <button class="css_btn_class" type="submit">Atualizar</button>
</form>
```

**OBS:** Vc ainda pode usar `title="O ano deve ter 4 dígitos"` e `x-moz-errormessage="O ano deve ter 4 dígitos"` para fazer tipo um *Tooltip* quando o usuário colocar o mouse no sobre `input`

Referencia sobre o Input Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/data

Answer (score 2):

Além de uma verificação na função, você pode utilizar o recurso `pattern` do HTML5 que só irá aceitar no campo números e a barra "`/`" e com 10 caracteres de tamanho:

```
pattern="[\d/]{10}"
```

Na função você faz a verificação se o tamanho da string é diferente de 10 e chama um *alert*:

```js
function verifica(){
   var data_dd = document.querySelector("input[name='Data_dd']").value;
   if(data_dd.length != 10){
       alert("Data inválida");
       return false;
   }
}

function formatar(mascara, documento){
  var i = documento.value.length;
  var saida = mascara.substring(0,1);
  var texto = mascara.substring(i);
  if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
    event.returnValue = false;
  }
  
  if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
            documento.value += texto.substring(0,1);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form class="got" method="GET" action="Dia_rtd.php" name="troca" onsubmit="return verifica()">
    <input pattern="[\d/]{10}" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Data" name="Data_dd" OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" style="width:70px;"/> 
     <button class="css_btn_class" type="submit">Atualizar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usei uma função expressão regular muito simples para verificar se a data está no formato correto, caso esteja ele envia o formulário, caso contrário ele não vai enviar. Segue o código

```js
function formatar(mascara, documento) {
  var i = documento.value.length;
  var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
  var texto = mascara.substring(i);
  if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
    event.returnValue = false;
  }
  if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
    documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
  }
}

function salvar() {
  value = document.getElementById("data").value;
  re = /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/;
  if(re.test( value )){
    alert('Data válida');
    document.troca.submit();
  }else{
    alert('Data inválida');
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" class="got" method="GET" action="Dia_rtd.php" name="troca" onsubmit="verifica(this)">

  <input id="data" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Data" name="Data_dd" OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" style="width:70px;" />
  <button class="css_btn_class" type="submit" onclick="salvar(); return false;">Atualizar</button>
</form>
```